# TO find Target and Achievement in mongodb database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate, mongoose-populate

I am trying to develope a app in node.js using express

I have three different shcmeas for activity, target and bfdwork

I have been trying to get the below mentioned things but somehow unable to figure out how

1. I want monthly report
2. A report which can caculate how much tragets are achieved and how much left for the particular month
3. The remaining targets from pevious month should get carryforwarded to next month

I have used aggregate function but it is not pouplating activity and I am unable to get the target aligned with it

Can any one help in this?

```
1) Activity Schema 
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var addactivitySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    nmeofactivity:
    {type:String,
    required:true,
    unique:true
    },
    categoryofactivity:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
    }
});



module.exports=mongoose.model("Addactivity", addactivitySchema);

2) BFD work

//schema to add activities
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Addactivity = require("./addactivity");
var Village = require("./village");
var User = require("./users");

var bfdworkSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    nameofbfd:{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
    activityname:{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Addactivity'
  },
    villagename:{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Village'
  },
    wadiname:{type: String, required:true},
    dateofcamp:{type: Date, required:true},
    beneficiaries:{type:Number, required:true},
    followup:{type:Number},
    treatment:{type:Number},
    
    
    createdon:{ type: Date, default: Date.now }

});



module.exports=mongoose.model("BFDWork", bfdworkSchema);

3) Target Schema 

//schema for targets
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Addactivity = require("./addactivity");

var targetSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    year:Number,
    activity: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Addactivity'
  },
    jantarget:Number,
    febtarget:Number,
    martarget:Number,
    aprtarget:Number,
    maytarget:Number,
    juntarget:Number,
    jultarget:Number,
    augtarget:Number,
    septarget:Number,
    octtarget:Number,
    novtarget:Number,
    dectarget:Number,
    createdon:{ type: Date, default: Date.now },
});

module.exports=mongoose.model("Target", targetSchema);

Below is the aggregate code
app.get("/getdata", (req,res)=>{
    res.render("totalwork");
});

app.post("/getdata", (req, res) => {
  const startDate = new Date(req.body.fromdate);
  const endDate = new Date(req.body.todate);
  BFDWork.find({})
.populate('activityname')   
  BFDWork.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        dateofcamp: {
          $gte: startDate,
          $lte: endDate
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: "$activityname",
        totalBeneficiaries: { $sum: "$beneficiaries" },
        count: { $sum: 1 }
      }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        _id: 0,
        activity: "$_id",
        totalBeneficiaries: 1,
        count: 1
      }
    }
  ])
    
  .exec(function(err, results) {
    if (err) {
      // Handle error
    } else {
      Target.find({}, (err, foundtarget)=>{
          if(err){
              res.redirect("/");
              console.log(err);
          }else{
              Addactivity.find({}, (err, foundacti)=>{
                  if(err){
                      console.log(err);
                      res.redirect("/");
                  }else{
                      res.render("showdata", {results:results, foundtarget:foundtarget, foundacti:foundacti});  
                  }
              })
              
          }
      });
    
    }
  });
});
```